# TabLayout selected indicator - must select tab twice

Tags: android, android-studio, android-tablayout

I'm able to navigate between the tabs in my TabLayout, but only if I select the tab twice does the indicator highlight follow that selection.

For example, from the home tab I will select the quiz tab. The layout for the quiz displays, but the selected indicator under the tab icon remains on home. If I select quiz a second time, then the indicator will follow.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as I thought what I'd been doing was pretty standard, but here's my code that handles tab selects.

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            switch (tab.getPosition()){

                case 1:
                    Intent infoIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, about.class);
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(infoIntent);
                    break;

                case 2:

                    Intent studentIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, student.class);
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(studentIntent);
                    break;

                case 3:

                    Intent surveyIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, survey.class);
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(surveyIntent);
                    break;

                case 4:

                    Intent quizIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, quiz.class);
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(quizIntent);
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

am i missing something?

Comment: where is your logic for when the user selects the tab twice?  and when he doesn't?

Comment: Can you describe/show the layout of quiz and mainactivity?

Comment: @ScottS I don't handle a second tab select, should I be doing that? the problem arises just from the first select.

Comment: @Alex mainactivity is huge, but this is all I have for the tab events in there. quiz and all my other activities are identical, but they don't handle the case in which itself is selected. ex. here in main case 0 is not handled because i am already in pos 0. in quiz i would not handle case 4 because its own position is 4

Comment: "the problem arises just from the first select." if that's the case, look into the differences between the first case and all the others. My geuss would be, that in quiz the update of the tabscreen is blocked, and it is updated when you click on the tab for the second time.

Comment: Okay I'll look into my other activities more. But to your knowledge the way I'm using intents in TabLayouts seems to be correct?

Answer (score 2):

It might not be the best way, but I solved this by simply putting

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(index).select();
```

in each of my activities onCreate. Thanks for the suggestions